# loadrunner get js variable

Tags: loadrunner

i have a problem on loadrunner testing.when i was recording script for sap ep logon,there is a parameter named windowid need correlation.so i use the code below:

```
 web_reg_save_param_ex(
        "ParamName=windowId",
        "LB=?windowId=",
        "RB=style=",
        SEARCH_FILTERS,
        "Scope=ALL",
        "IgnoreRedirections=Yes",
        LAST);
```

but what get is js code! the result is   `"+ EPCM.getUniqueWindowId() +'"`.how could get the js variable?Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript variable would be in the local stack on the browser and not in the functional code for execution coming back.    What you can do is collect the algorithm used to generate the ID and convert it to the language of your virtual user.   You can then run the same code locally which would be executed in the browser and use the value as you see fit.

But, it is likely far simpler then this....Record your Script twice.  Vary as few elements as possible in the business process as this will place emphasis in the dynamic elements on the areas of session, state, time and any instance object identifiers, such as window ID, which may be changing from session to session.   In greater than 95% of such cases reproducing the JavaScript algorithm in 'C' is not required as the identifier in question can be pulled from the return data stream.

James Pulley

Answer (score 0):

actually,i use the wrong protocol,to record the action in sap ep you'd better using sap web protocol.